# How do the guilty remnant get money?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-leftovers

The guilty remnant in *The Leftovers* have houses, cars for transport, food, pens, paper and money for smokes. Where do they get this as the members stop working once they join?

Answer (score 6):

They make money by having their members give them their estates. If a member joins the Remnant, they are expected to give their entire wealth to the Remnant, spouses divorce to get more assets; this is seen in the show and the book when Laurie divorces Kevin, so that she gets half his assets to go toward the cult.

Comment: "His" assets is a bit misleading;  it was strongly implied in S1E9 ("The Garveys At Their Best") that Laurie was the primary breadwinner when the two of them were married, and that Kevin was unhappy about this fact.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert